# Regex for trailing slash and includes hompage "/"

Tags: regex

I am using this Regex as a filter to capture all of my pages that have a trailing slash (as opposed to their identical non-trailing slash versions)

```
^(/[a-z0–9/_\-]*[/])$
```

I see that it filters exactly what I want except for the homepage which is `"/"` in google analytics. How can I include all of my pages `/mypage/`, `/features/`, `/blog/this-is-my-blog-title` in the report and exclude their alter egos of `/mypage`, `/features`, `/blog/this-is-my-blog-title` in the expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression:

```regex
\/(?:[\w-]+\/)*
```

[Check it out at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uYG2J2/3), which also includes an explanation of how the regex will perform the matching.

Comment: `\d` is part of `\w`; you can remove `\d`

Comment: Also, slashes do not need escaping - they have no special regex meaning (although some languages use the slash as a regex delimiter, slashes are nevertheless nothing special).

Comment: Neither does the dash `-`.  Dashes are only used as ranges when they are between two characters in a character class, but in this case, you have the dash at the end of the character class, so you don't need to escape it.

Comment: Also, depending on the tool, the `^` and `$` may be able to be removed - try it and see if you can simplify it still further.

Comment: @Bohemian and @Charlie Armstrong Thanks for the suggestions! I've updated my answer. Regarding the slashes, I left them to make the regex universal since not escaping them gives a pattern error in some languages that treat `/` differently, such as PHP and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

To get the same exact meaning as your current regex, but allow a single `/`, just add it in as an "or" option.  The "or" character in regex is `|`.  So something like this would work:

```
^(/[a-z0–9/_\-]*[/]|/)$
```

One minor improvement you can make is to take the third `/` out of the character class, since it is only one character.  You might as well just match it literally.  You also don't need to escape the `-`, since it is at the end of the character class:

```
^(/[a-z0–9/_-]*/|/)$
```

Now this still has the same exact meaning as your original regex, and it also captures a single `/`.  There are a lot of other conditions in this regex, though.  If you just want to check for any string ending in a `/`, you can shorten it way down to this:

```
^.*/$
```

This will match any string that ends in a `/`, including just a single `/`.  It also happens to be much shorter and a little bit faster than your original regex.  Here's a breakdown of this updated regex:

- `^` This match has to start at the start of the string
- `.*` Match 0 or more of any characters
- `/` Match a literal `/`.  This ensures that the string ends in a `/`.
- `$` This match has to end at the end of the string.  This ensures that the `/` was actually at the end of the string, and not halfway through.

Answer (score 0):

Your homepage path is one character long, so simply replacing `*` with `+` in your regex will exclude it:

```
^(/[a-z0–9/_\-]+[/])$
```

But to match paths ending in /, I’d write just

```
^.+/$
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the OP's question.  The way I read it, they **do** want to capture the homepage (`/`) in their regex.  Their current regex does not.